# Java: Get sum of child node values in a nested xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to make a program which outputs the price of a specific element in an xml file.
The xml file looks like this:

```
<list name="root">
<book name="B1" price="30" isbn="123"/>
<list name="L1">
 <book name="B2" price="20" isbn="234"/>
 <list name="L2">
  <cd name="C1" price="15"/>
  <cd name="C2" price="5"/>
  <book name="B3" price="10" isbn="345"/>
 </list>
 <cd name="C3" price="15"/>
 <book name="B4" price="60" isbn="456"/> 
</list>
</list>
```

My program should output something like this:

> getPrice(B1) = 30;
>
> getPrice(L1) = B2+L2+C3+B4 = 125 ...

My idea is to store the names and values in a hashmap, and then get the values from it. But, I have troubles getting the price for the nested lists. The program should work for different xml files as well. Only the types (cd, book and list) will be the same.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class ManageList implements Assignment7 {

    private HashMap<String, Double> data = new HashMap<String, Double>();


    @Override
    public void loadXml(File input) throws Exception {

        // given in the readme
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        // get filename => absolute path
        String filename = input.getAbsolutePath();

        Document doc = db.parse(new File(filename));

        // Normalize the XML Structure
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        // get the root element from XML document
        // Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        // ####################################
        // acces elements and their attributes and store it in a hashmap
        // ####################################

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

        storeNodes(nl);

        //System.out.println(Arrays.asList(data)); 

    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Double> getPrice(String item) {

        return null;
    }

    public void storeNodes(NodeList nl) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nl.item(i);
            int type = n.getNodeType();
            if (type == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element e = (Element) n;

                if (e.getTagName() == "book" || e.getTagName() == "cd") {

                    data.put(e.getAttribute("name"), Double.parseDouble(e.getAttribute("price")));
                }

                if (e.getTagName() == "list" && n.hasChildNodes()) {

                    String name = e.getAttribute("name");

                    //here i get a NumberFormatException
                    //data.put(name, Double.parseDouble(e.getAttribute("price")));


                    //just to show output
                    data.put(name, 0.0);



                }

                storeNodes(n.getChildNodes());
            }

        }

    }
```

Hashmap output:

```
[{B2=20.0, C3=15.0, B3=10.0, B4=60.0, L1=0.0, L2=0.0, root=0.0, C1=15.0, B1=30.0, C2=5.0}]
```

How can I get the values for the nested Lists?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `list` contains sub attributes, looping from `nList.getLength()-1` to `0` will avoid so many problems.

For list we need values(prices) of sub attributes `book` and `cd`. So looping from last to first will help us in storing the values of sub attributes in `data` as a prior step.

Now, For us to get total price of list, we iterate all over NodeList of books and cd.
we sum up all the values which makes the price of the list.

Below is the code if `(e.getTagName() == "list" && n.hasChildNodes()`,

```
NodeList books = e.getElementsByTagName("book");
NodeList cd = e.getElementsByTagName("cd");
System.out.println(books.getLength());
System.out.println(cd.getLength());

double listPrice = 0;
for(int i=0;i<books.getLength();i++) {
 Node t = books.item(i);
 Element e1 = (Element)t;

 /**This can be reduced if we loop from nList.getLength()-1 to 0, Since the data already exists in data.
 //if (!data.containsKey(e1.getAttribute("name"))){
 //    data.put(e1.getAttribute("name"),Double.parseDouble(e1.getAttribute("price")));
 //
 //}
 */


 listPrice += Double.parseDouble(e1.getAttribute("price"));
}

for(int i=0;i<cd.getLength();i++){
 Node t = cd.item(i);
 Element e1 = (Element)t;
 listPrice += Double.parseDouble(e1.getAttribute("price"));
}
```

for any doubts - comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this will solve my problem.

Comment: glad it helped!!:)